# Search multiple row separate by comma from mysql using php

Tags: php, mysql, forms, explode, implode

It is a tracking system like DHL. Tracking shipment number from MySQL database using php form.
but I need it Search multiple row separate by comma from mysql using php.
[image]

```
<?php 
      $ship=$_POST['Consignment'];
      $cons = explode(',',$ship);
?>

<?php
    $sql = "SELECT * FROM tbl_courier WHERE cons_no = '$cons[]'";
    $result = dbQuery($sql);
    $no = dbNumRows($result);
    if($no == 1){
    while($data = dbFetchAssoc($result)) {      
    extract($data);
?>

 Shipment Name: <?php echo $ship_name; ?>
 Shipment Phone: <?php echo $phone; ?>

 <?php }//while
        }//if
         else {
         echo 'In else....';
 ?>
    Consignment Number not found.Search Again.

    <?php 
                }//else
    ?>
```

So I need my search will work with separating by comma(,).
Thanks for helping me.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the Answer:

```
if(isset($_POST['Consignment'])){

    $ship=$_POST['Consignment'];
    $shipment= explode(',',$_POST['Consignment']);

$ship = implode("', '",$shipment) ;
$query = "SELECT * FROM `tbl_courier` WHERE `cons_no` IN('$ship')";

$results = $mysqli->query($query);

if($results){
print '<table border="1">';
while($row = $results->fetch_assoc()) {
    print '<tr>';
    print '<td>'.$row["cons_no"].'</td>';
    print '<td>'.$row["customerName"].'</td>';
    print '<td>'.$row["customerPhone"].'</td>';
    print '</tr>';
}  
print '</table>';

// Frees the memory associated with a result
$results->free();
}
else {
    echo "Query Not Match";
}
$mysqli->close();
}
```

Thanks to Answer.

Answer (score 2):

You can use IN operator in that case.

```
<?php 
      $ship=$_POST['Consignment'];

?>

<?php
    $sql = "SELECT * FROM tbl_courier WHERE cons_no IN(".$ship.")";
    $result = dbQuery($sql);
    $no = dbNumRows($result);
    if($no == 1){
    while($data = dbFetchAssoc($result)) {      
    extract($data);
?>
```

Hope it will help to you.

Comment: thanks but how I will separate my consignment no by comma?

Comment: You do not need to separate by comma because you have to pass consignment number with comma in IN operator

Answer (score 1):

change your sql query you have written '$cons[]' in select query which is wrong . after explode you will get data as 1,2,3 so you just need to write variable in query not array and user IN Operator like this.

```
 `$sql = "SELECT * FROM tbl_courier WHERE cons_no IN(".$ship.")";`
```

Answer (score 1):

You should always prepare/sanitize the `POST` data before using it in `MySql` query (in terms of security):

```
<?php

if (isset[$_POST['Consignment']] && !empty($_POST['Consignment'])) {
    $ship = $_POST['Consignment'];
    $cons = explode(',', $ship);
    $cons = array_filter($cons, function($v){
        return trim(strip_tags($v));
    });
    $cons = '"' . implode('","', $cons) . '"';


    $sql = "SELECT * FROM tbl_courier WHERE cons_no IN ($cons)";
    $result = dbQuery($sql);
    $no = dbNumRows($result);
    if ($no == 1) {
        while ($data = dbFetchAssoc($result)) {      
            extract($data);
        ....
    } 
    ....
}

?>
```

Answer (score 0):

Please Use Find IN SET

```
SELECT * FROM tbl_courier WHERE FIND_IN_SET(cons_no,'1,2,3,4,5')
```

Updated

```
SELECT * FROM tbl_courier WHERE FIND_IN_SET(cons_no,'$ship')
```

Note :- $ship Comma Separated Value not an array

Comment: `FIND_IN_SET` will return the position of the string within a list. That's not what the OP need

Comment: Look it will come from php form value of input , how can I use 1,2,3,4,5 ?

Comment: check my answer again